# Animaciones de imagenes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

Hola eh creado un stackpanel donde coloque tes imágenes ubicadas en la misma posición, lo que quiero es que cada imagen se muestre una a una por 5 segundos

```
 <StackPanel x:Name="derecho" Margin="250,50,40,50">

        <Image x:Name="img1" Height="300" Width="300" Source="C:icono.png"/>
        <Image x:Name="img2" Margin="0,-300,0,0" Height="300" Width="300" Source="C:img_logo_sistema.png" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <Image x:Name="img3" Margin="0,-300,0,0" Height="300" Width="300" Source="C:img_loguito.png" Visibility="Hidden"/>


    </StackPanel>
```

creado en WPF y C#

Comment: ¿Necesitas aplicar algún tipo de animación de transición? Porque podría usarse un único control `Image` y cambiar la imagen cada 5 segundos con un cronómetro, utilizando código C#.

Comment: Si se podría usar la transición, pero como lo haría?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede realizar mediante Storyboards, en este caso, omitiré animaciones de opacidad y solo se cambiará la propiedad de visibilidad de las imágenes. Debido a que en apariencia todas las imágenes tienen el mismo tamaño, decidí emplear un `Grid` para evitar ajustar la posición de las imágenes mediante la propiedad de margen.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <!--Animación-->
        <Storyboard x:Key="Secuencia">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="img1">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="img2">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="img3">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:15" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.Triggers>
        <!--Se desencadena la animación al cargar la ventana-->
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Secuencia}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>

    <Grid>
        <!--Controles de imagen, se puede usar Grid en lugar de StackPanel para evitar ajustar la posición de las imágenes-->
        <Grid Height="300" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Image x:Name="img1" Source="res/img1.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="img2" Source="res/img2.png" />
            <Image x:Name="img3" Source="res/img3.png" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

El `Storyboard` denominado **Secuencia** realiza el cambio de visibilidad de las imágenes. Este es ejecutado por el `EventTrigger` de carga de la ventana.
Si deseas que la animación se repita indefinidamente, se puede agregar el atributo `RepeatBehavior="Forever"` en la etiqueta de apertura del `Storyboard`.

Comment: Para los UserControl seria igual?

Comment: Sí. Sólo hace falta cambiar el prefijo `Window` por `UserControl`, es decir, en vez de `Window.Resources` sería `UserControl.Resources` y así con lo demás que tenga la palabra __Window__.